# Test dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I read a lot about reusing table cells in different questions here.

1. I implemented a subclass of UITableview (in Swift)
2. Registered this class in ViewDidLoad() of my ViewController (I'm not using storyboard)
3. and use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexpath in tableView's
   cellForRowAtIndexPath

As far as i know this should reuse the cells.
However is there a way to **test** if the cells are actually reused? 
For example in Instruments or by printing in the debugger.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you print the cell in the debugger it should give you the address of the cell object, which will tell you whether you are dealing with the same object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a number of ways to do it.

First of all, you can just write something to log in the `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:`. You'll see as much log entries as there are cells on the screen at the same time.

Second: you can mark your cells somehow in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. For instance, cells have tags which are set to `0` by default. So when you get a cell from `dequeueReusableCell...`, if it has a tag, which is equal to `0`, you set it to something else. Otherwise, you've just received a reused cell. You can also set the tag of the first cell to 1, then 2 for the second cell, etc. This way you'll also find out the number of cells that you use. You just need to keep track of the largest tag so far.

You can also add some custom property and use it the same way as the tag.

Another option is to print cells in the debugger. as @RichTolley suggested in a comment above. But to my mind it is not very convenient (manually comparing pointers to every cell).

Comment: I logged it in the initialization of my custom cell (print in debugger). There are 15 cells on my screen and 16 logs. The datasource contains about 30 cells. So the reusing should work ?! Thank you!

Comment: @Netzer, yes, seems so :) if there are no new records in log when you scroll, it works. Glad I could help :) please consider upvoting/accepting the answer. Have a nice day)

Answer (score 1):

The eayest way is to set a tag in cell for `cell.tag = indexPath.row+1` (add one prevent from set default 0 value) and set breakpoint condition as on the picture. If tag will be different than 0 breakpoint stops and print tag on console. [How to set condition breakepoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUnT8.png)